# configuring location w/ UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, indexpath

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    
    }
    
    @objc func doubleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: sender.view))

        if let unwrapped = indexPath {
```

For some reason, indexPath is always nil here. Does anyone see the bug in my code?

Comment: try `let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: self.collectionView))`

Comment: @Paulw11 it works thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the tap position in your collection view, not the super view.

Use `let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: self.collectionView))`